# express serve index.html from create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

for special Heroku purposes, I need to deploy the solution which would redirect all routes to create-react-app index.html.

```
$ tree -L 2 -I 'node_modules|temp|semantic|build'
.
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html // all requests from "redirect" express app should point to this file
│   ├── libs
│   ├── manifest.json
│   └── semantic.css
├── README.md
├── redirect // express app
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── bin
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── public
│   ├── views
│   └── yarn.lock
├── semantic.json
├── src
│   ├── appConfig.js
│   ├── assets
│   ├── components
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── index.scss
│   ├── old
│   ├── pages
│   ├── serviceWorker.js
│   └── utils
├── yarn.lock
└── yarn-error.log
```

the `redirect` directory contains the express app where I need to redirect every request to index.html

everything is fine but in the index.html there is env variable %PUBLIC_URL% which would fail with error below when I run npm start from redirect folder

```
pandemic@bar ~/foo/redirect
$ npm start

> redirect@0.0.0 start <path>\redirect
> node ./bin/www

URIError: Failed to decode param '/%PUBLIC_URL%/libs/pdfmake/pdfmake.min.js'
```

How to resolve this issue?

**note**: I am using windows

Comment: don't you need to replace %PUBLIC_URL% with your url?

Comment: yes, %PUBLIC_URL% is replaced correctly if I run `npm start` in root but its not correctly replaced when I ran `npm start` from `redirect` folder where the express app is